# PDFBOX - Invalid characters codes with AR PL Zenkai Uni Font

Tags: pdfbox

PdfBox 2.0.24.
Hi, I'm developing a PDF writer and I need to use "AR PL Zenkai Uni Font".
When I try to load it PDFBox crash with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Invalid characters codes
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable.processSubtype12(CmapSubtable.java:257)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapSubtable.initSubtable(CmapSubtable.java:111)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.CmapTable.read(CmapTable.java:86)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont.readTable(TrueTypeFont.java:361)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:173)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:150)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:106)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.load(PDType0Font.java:97)
at com.vgs.pdf.PDFCreatorSandbox.main(PDFCreatorSandbox.java:166)e here
```

To load this font i'm usign the following code:

```
    PDType0Font brokenFont = PDType0Font.load(document, new FileInputStream("font/ukai.ttf"), false);
```

This code was run on Windows 10 with java 1.8.0_291
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share this font.

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/ukai1 Thanks in advance

Comment: There is an invalid character code 0x209AA8 in that subtable (the error message is incomplete). That isn't valid unicode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52203351/why-unicode-is-restricted-to-0x10ffff