# Don't understand the characters in C++ window

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a basic project, that should just open the window to a blank one, with the name 'Yes'. Instead, I get these weird foreign symbols. I've seen a couple others report this same issue a while back. I'm new to C++ so maybe it's something simple? I do not have any errors in my IDE, and I am using Visual Studio.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

bool running = true;

void* buffer_memory;
BITMAPINFO buffer_bitmap_info;

LRESULT CALLBACK window_callback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMSG, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    LRESULT result = 0;

    switch (uMSG) {
    case WM_CLOSE:
    case WM_DESTROY: {
        running = false;
    } break;

    case WM_SIZE: {
        RECT rect;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
        int buffer_width = rect.right - rect.left;
        int buffer_height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

        int buffer_size = buffer_width * buffer_height * sizeof(unsigned int);

        if (buffer_memory) VirtualFree(buffer_memory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        buffer_memory = VirtualAlloc(0, buffer_size, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

        buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader);
        buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biWidth = buffer_width;
        buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biHeight = -buffer_height;
        buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
        buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
        buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    } break;

    default: {
        result = DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMSG, wParam, lParam);
    }

    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    return WinMain(GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, GetCommandLineA(), SW_SHOW);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) {
    // Create Window Class
    WNDCLASSA window_class = {};
    window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    window_class.lpszClassName = "Game_Window_Class";
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = window_callback;

    // Register Class
    RegisterClassA(&window_class);

    // Create Window
    CreateWindowA(window_class.lpszClassName, "Yes", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1920, 1080, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    while (running) {
        // Input
        MSG message;
        while (PeekMessageA(&message, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            TranslateMessage(&message);
            DispatchMessageA(&message);
        }

        // Simulate

        // Render
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the name to be 'Yes' instead of what is on the image. The only time it does not put the symbols is when I use one letter.

[image: Picture that contains weird symbols instead of the proper English title]

Comment: There's no "Game" in your code.

Comment: You registered the class with RegisterClassA, but your window procedure uses DefWindowProc instead of DefWindowProcA. Pick a team and stick with it. Team A: Use A suffixes consistently (obsolete). Team W: Use W suffixes consistently. Team null: Use no suffixes consistently.

Comment: I updated my question, I meant to say 'Yes' I initially had it set to show 'Game' but changed it.

Comment: Stop mixing Unicode (W) and ANSI (A) versions of API calls. If you're going to use the ones ending with `A`, then use the A versions of everything. But better yet, don't use either A or W, and just use the bare functions, and let the compiler decide which one should be used.

Comment: @KenWhite "*just use the bare functions, and let the compiler decide which one [A or W] should be used*" - in order to do that successfully, string literals used with the APIs need to be wrapped in `TEXT()`

Comment: Using wide-character literal also can fix it. Just convert the type and add `L` like this: `(LPCSTR)L"Yes"`.

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT `(LPCSTR)L"Yes"` is not ever not a mistake.

Comment: Why are you so keen to use ANSI in 2023?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan [MS suggested that nowadays so that we can use UTF-8 for portability](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63454192/995714)

Comment: @phuclv  this looks like ansi rather than utf8

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the `-A` API is used for all single-byte code-unit character sets including [MBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi_Byte_Character_Set) or UTF-8. The `-W` version is exclusively for UTF-16

Comment: @phuclv if this was UTF8 we wouldn't see Chinese characters

Comment: @DavidHeffernan why not? UTF-8 can represent **all** Unicode characters because it's just another encoding for Unicode just like UTF-7, UTF-16 or UTF-32. In fact the limits in UTF-16 and UTF-32 [are exactly because of UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52203351/995714)

Comment: @phuclv if this was an A API with a UTF8 locale then we wouldn't see this. This is, 100%, 8 bit text interpreted as UTF16. I mean I suppose the user could have some 8 bit UTF8 text, but the text in the Q is ascii in char arrays and it's being interpreted as if it were utf16